# Power BI filter shows additional value and selects it

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm applying a filter to my report on just one id but when the report is loaded it shows two id's and selects one id by default which I'm not passing to my filter

Below is my filter code:

```
var companyFilter = {
$schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
target: {
table: "Company",
column: "Company ID"
},
operator: 'In',
values: [1]
};
```

and below is the output:

[image: Report Filter]

Comment: You said you are applying the filter to your report - is that through `report.setFilters([filter])`? Or are you setting the filter by modifying the slicer visual? Furthermore, I'm wondering if the field that you have linked to the slicer visual in your screenshot is maybe not the same as you are using in your companyFilter - you might want to check that those align, and that the data is really integer based and not a string (or else it should be `value: ["1"]`).

Comment: @JoshuaT Datatype is correct because i have 9 company id's in total and if i remove the the filter i get the below result

![slicer](https://i.imgur.com/GgwmdYN.png)

if you see if i remove filter it selects company id 2 by default as well.
and I'm applying filter through config 

    var config = {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType:models.TokenType.Embed, 
    accessToken: accessToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    filters:[companyFilter]}

Comment: okay i found the solution, problem was company id 2 was selected on power bi portal and when i was embedding it and applying filter on id 1 in javascript it was selecting value 2 which was selected on portal but was not showing anything. I removed all the selections from portal and problem was gone. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution!